# c++ pointer vector<base_class*> put derived class but sliced print

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, derived-class

I'm studying for pointer and inheritance of C++.\

I made pointer of vector Employee class which has name and salary in it.
Also, it has print function which printout name and salary.

I made it virtual

```
   virtual void print() const;
```

Also here's the implementation of function

```
void Employee::print() const
{
    cout << "Inquiry Employee info..." << endl;
    cout <<  "Name:" << get_name() << "\n";
    cout << "Salary:" <<  get_salary() << "\n" << "\n";
}
```

In derived class, I added one more private data Department Name and override print function.
I put derived class in pointer vector, and tried to call the function on derived function.
However, it only calls the function in base class.

When I make derived class object itself and called that print function, it worked.

What should I change to make derived class object in base class pointer vector can call function in derived class?

Addition ##

```
#ifndef MANAGER_H
#define MANAGER_H

#include <string>
#include<iostream>
#include "ccc_empl.h"
#include <iomanip>

class Manager : public Employee
{
public:
    Manager();
    Manager(string name, double salary, string dept);
    ~Manager();
    virtual string get_department() const;
    void print();

private:
    string deptName;
};
#endif
```

implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "manager.h"
#include "ccc_empl.h"
Manager::Manager(){}
Manager::Manager(string name, double salary, string dept)
: Employee(name,salary)
{
    deptName = dept;
}
Manager::~Manager(){}
string Manager::get_department() const
{
    return deptName;
}
void Manager::print()
{
    cout << "Inquiry Manager info..." << endl;
    cout << "Name:" << get_name()  << "\n";
    cout << "Salary:";
    cout  << get_salary() << "\n";
    cout <<  "Department:"<< get_department() << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: For some reason you haven't shown us the Derived class print function, but if I had to guess I would say that you forgot to declare it const.

Comment: Please post a minimal complete compilable example of your problem.

Comment: I added my code but yea, I forgot to put const.. Thank you!

Comment: Where is your pointer vector?
print() is not virtual.

Comment: @john: I guess you can make it an answer now

Comment: Yep, @john is right. You need to match the function definition exactly for the override to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown us the Derived class print function, but I would guess that you forgot to declare it const. Easy mistake to make.